# SQL Select Certain row from result

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name = fred "; // THIS LINE SHOULD NOT BE CHANGED
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
for ($res = array (); $res = $result->fetch_assoc(); $charDB[array_shift($row)] = $res);
```

then for example the 2nd result returned (just an example), I want to echo onto the screen. So something like  `$res[1]` to get the 2nd row only.

The problem is at the moment it is treating the number in `[]` as the primary key for the row in the DB rather than the returned result number. Basically, I want to treat each row that is returned by its position in the array rather than the primary key in the db.

How would I achieve something like this? I have tried using `fetch_object`, `fetch_array` & `fetch_row` but none of them did what I wanted. I think it's something pretty basic?

Please let me know if it didn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `$charDB[array_shift($row)] = $res` in your `for` expression...

You are telling php to [shift an element off the beginning of the row](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) and use that first element value as the key for each stored row.  **You don't want this**.

To correct your method, you don't need to make any additional function calls (like `array_values()`), [you just need to let php index the elements for you as you store resultset rows to your `$res` variable](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php#112924).

Use this and everything will be as you desire:

```
for($charDB=[]; $row=$result->fetch_assoc(); $charDB[]=$row);
```

Please take notice to the variable name changes I've made versus your original code.

p.s. I'll assume that `fred` is single-quote wrapped in the query of your actual project.